# Help with some mocking

Tags: .net, mocking, nmock2, nmock-2.1

I was trying to mock an interface and I got the next expection:

> System.TypeLoadException:  System.TypeLoadException: Signature of the body and declaration in a method implementation do not match

I figured out later that my problem was a function that I have defined in my interface:

```
IList<T> GetAll<T>() where T : class, new();
```

Please could you tell me how to define the class so it would work with nmock2?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know anything about nmock2, but it might help to show some code of how you're using it in your tests.

Comment: "Just don't pay any attention to those boys, dear, they're just jealous"  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was my nmock2 version, I had 2 and when I replaced it with 1.x it worked.